# Google Chrome Extensions: Popup window like Firebug Lite?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to pop open a little window/frame like Firebug Lite does when you click the browser action. I know how to detect the click event in the background page, but how do I produce a an embedded window like that? That's not done with standard javascript is it?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome API doesn't provide any tools for creating GUI elements, so everything needs to be done in pure javascript and css.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have used Notifications once..its pretty cool ;)
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html

this will do the job , imo .

Comment: No...not notifications. An actual window. That I can render HTML inside. Like a popup window, except by default it's locked inside the tab.